# Find the vector function of the intersection of the surfaces $z={x}^{2}+{y}^{2}$ and 2xy=z

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

I am trying to find the vector intersection of

$z={x}^{2}+{y}^{2}$
and 
$2xy=z$

I am usually pretty good at this but I can not figure out which part of the vector function to set to t.

Comment: why are you searching for a vector function?

Comment: The goal would be to have [x=f(t), y=g(t), z=h(t)]

Comment: I'm also confused. Whats wrong with setting them equal? $(x-y)^2 = 0$ implies $x = y$. I guess you want it then to be $(t, t, 2t^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

If $(x',y',z')$ is a point in the intersection of these , then we get $(x'-y')^2=0$, or $x'=y'=k$ (say) and $z'=2k^2$. And any point of the form $(k,k,2k^2)$ satisfies both the equations.

Comment: Where did you get (x'-y')^2=0

Comment: $2xy=z=x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 0):

solving your two equations we will have
$$2xy=x^2+y^2$$ and then we get after dividing by $$xy\neq 0$$
$$2=\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}$$ this is equivalent to
$$\left(\frac{x}{y}-1\right)^2=0$$
it follows $$x=y,z=2x^2=2y^2$$